# No puedo modificar registro de tabla usando EF

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tengo la siquiente tabla en SQL, la cual tiene esos 4 datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mediante EF estoy tratando de actualizar los registros digamos del ID 3 para que sea "40" pero por mas que trato la cantidad siempre queda en cero

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando:

```
/*SE AGREGA SALDO AL SALDO EXISTENTE*/
        public void addSaldo(int idx, int sal)
        {
            var datos = new Saldos
            {
                id = idx,
                Cantidad = sal
            };

            using (var ctx = new ModeloProductos())
            {
                ctx.Entry(datos).State= EntityState.Modified;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es conceptual sobre el EF, para poder editar un objeto debes consultarlo primero, en tu ejemplo estás creando uno nuevo al instanciar con "new Saldos". Intenta lo siguiente:

```
public void addSaldo(int idx, int sal)
{
    using (var ctx = new ModeloProductos())
    {
        var entidad = ctx.Saldos.Where(w => w.id == idx).SingleOrDefault();
        entidad.Cantidad = sal;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: `The property 'Cantidad' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.` Lanza ese error

Comment: Pusiste la Cantidad como llave primaria, no debería si deseas modificarla

Comment: El problema es que ya le quite su propiedad de llave primaria (desde SQL, no se si hay que hacer modificacion en el modelo de EF) y sigue dando igual

Comment: Si el modelo EF lo generaste a partir de la base, debes darle actualizar para que tome esa modificación.